# Status of JSONP security

Tags: ajax, security, jsonp

There [have](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/json-and-jsonp/) [been](http://qfox.nl/weblog/215) [many](http://qfox.nl/weblog/216) [proposals](http://json-p.org/) to enhance the security of JSONP communications - some of which fail to understand the point.

As things stand now, when one makes a JSONP request to some provider, he has to trust the provider to actually return some JSON data wrapped in a callback. Well, actually it is enough to trust the provider to wrap `anything` into a desired callback: we can use `JSON.parse` to be sure that `anything` is valid JSON. In any case, there is nothing stopping the provider to simply ignore the callback and return a malicious script.

The only way to make the mechanism secure is to add some enhancement on the client. The client should not blindly insert a script, but rather parse it **before** allowing it. This is, in essence, what many proposals advocate, but of course this requires some collaboration from the browser vendors. So we come to my question

> Is there any concrete proposal from some browser vendor to implement such a mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cross-domain XHR requests in browsers that have CORS support will probably be what eventually solves that problem.  Bringing the response in through XHR instead of script injection prevents unwanted code execution, and (as you mentioned) `JSON.parse()` can then be used to interpret/validate the JSON response.

Comment: Yes, I know about CORS, but it seems it is not very widespread at the moment. On the other hand, JSONP is here now, and it does not seems a very good model.

Comment: All the major browsers support CORS in their new versions. CORS is definitely gaining traction. JSONP is a hack that can be used till CORS is more widespread. There is no point in trying to improve browser support for a hack.

Comment: @Andrea: Right, but CORS is already filtering into the browser ecosystem.  It will be something you can depend on sooner than an even newer change to JSONP that wouldn't enter the ecosystem before IE10, Firefox 5, Chrome 25, etc.